# Applet - KeyListener not working

Tags: java, applet, awt, keylistener

When I start up my applet, I get no response from the key listener. How do I fix this? Below is the code.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main extends Applet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public String mode = "";
public Graphic gr;

public void init() {
    this.setSize(400, 400);
    gr = new Graphic();
    this.add(gr);
    gr.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                    gr.requestFocus();
            gr.repaint();
        }

    };
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000 / 5);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

}

private class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
    public MyKeyListener(){
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            gr.direction = Graphic.Direction.up;
            gr.move();

            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            gr.direction = Graphic.Direction.down;
            gr.move();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            gr.direction = Graphic.Direction.left;
            gr.move();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            gr.direction = Graphic.Direction.right;
            gr.move();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: *"I get no response from the key listener."*  Given code like `public void paint(Graphics g) {

}` I am surprised you get anything at all.  1) Why AWT in the 3rd millennium?  2) Why applet rather than frame?  3) Why `KeyListener` instead of Key Bindings?  4) Why no calls to any method mentioning 'focus'?  See the [focus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) tutorial for details. -- It seems you are trying to 'code by magic' when that typically does not work.

Comment: `this.setSize(400, 400);`  And don't do that.  An applet size is set by attributes in HTML.

Comment: Trying to grab focus using a timer like this is a horrible idea any time, NEVER do this (I know "just a test" - but the statement stands).  Avoid key listeners and favor [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) they don't suffer so much from the same focus issues as `KeyListener`s

Comment: I think setSize is still handy for testing on local machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class TTest extends Applet{
    @Override
    public void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.init();
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener());

    }
    class KeyListener extends KeyAdapter{
        public KeyListener(){

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.keyPressed(e);
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                System.out.println("Pressed up arrow!");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                System.out.println("Pressed down arrow!");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You pressed: " + e.getKeyCode());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You must add key event listener to applet itself not to graphic object. However, I think it is ok to add mouse event listener to objects apart from applet

Comment: 1- I think `Graphic` is there own class. 2- With respect to the complete lack of context, I'd avoid suggesting the use of `KeyListener`, there is a better API for this kind of thing - IMHO

Comment: I think the problem was caused at the above code is because when you deploy your program, the program is focused on applet object not to the graphic object. So inputs are not recognized from keyboard listener.