# KeyListener not reaching my switch statement

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have this code:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

    import javax.swing.JApplet;


    public class applet extends JApplet implements KeyListener, MouseListener{
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        public void init(){
            setSize(500,500);
            addKeyListener( this );
             addMouseListener( this );
        }
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(a, b, 400, 400);
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello!")    
switch(e.getKeyCode()){
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: a -= 5;
                break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP: a += 5;
                break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: b += 5;
                break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: b -= 5;
                break;
            }
            repaint();
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

and it is not even reaching the switch statement,as can be seen by my debug println code. Why is this happening, and what can i do to fix this? Please do not hate if this is too broad, as I am a complete noob on this topic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595208/applet-keylistener-not-working?rq=1

Comment: Also 1- Avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers, instead use something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and add that to the applet and 2- Make sure you call `super.paintXxx`

Comment: See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for problems with using a KeyListener and an example solution using Key Bindings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`KeyListener` will only fire events if the component it is registered is focusable and has focus.

`JApplet` has a `JRootPane` which adds a `JLayeredPane` and content pane (amongst other things) ontop of the applet, which may mean that key listener may never be capable of begin notified of events (as other elements are blocking it).

Instead, use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)